# Unresolved compilation problem exception using JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am a beginner in Java and I am trying to use JOptionPane to display a message box but keep getting stuck with an error which I cannot figure out. This is my code:

```
package excercise1; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Part3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int testVal = 20;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number is " + testVal);
    }

}
```

I keep getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       JOptionPane cannot be resolved
>
> at excercise1/excercise1.Part3.main(Part3.java:8)

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks!

EDIT: I am running this code in Eclipse by just clicking on the run button in the top toolbar, if I should be running this code differently please let me know.

EDIT #2: Screenshot of my Eclipse screen:
[image]

Comment: What are you using to write and run this? Can you add this information in your question please?

Comment: I suspect that your problem is related with the way you are running your code. It is working fine for me.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I just updated the question, but I am using Eclipse to run this code, should I be running it differently?

Comment: works fine for me on eclipse. FYI it's "exercise". can you share a screenshot from eclipse?

Comment: @algorythms Just edited the post including a screenshot of my Eclipse screen, thanks

Comment: there is an issue with your import. can you create a new package with just this class and see if it works?

Comment: Clean and re-build your Eclipse project.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just rebuilt project and created new package with just this class and it still gives same error message. Is there any additional libraries that I have to install to run this too?

Comment: @algorythms Just created new package with just this class and it still gave me the same error message, are there any extra libraries that I have to install to run this too?

Comment: Can you try installing a different JDK and then changing the system library of the project to that? (I think we are all just at this point where we try different turn-off-turn-on approaches.)

Comment: So, now that I know you are using Eclipse that became weird. So I would suggest first you open your project in the Project Explorer view (Window -> Show View -> Project Explorer) (instead of package Explorer)  then collapse the JRE System Library, see if all JRE jar files are under. After that select your project right click on it and click on properties, go to Java Build Path and see under the Order and Export tab if JRE System Library is selected... This is now a matter of configuration in your Eclipse, finding the right thing to change would be the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the JRE system library and adding it again:

Go to properties of project with the build error (right click > Properties)

View the "Libraries" tab in the "Build Path" section

Find the "JRE System Library" in the list (if this is missing then this error message is not an eclipse bug but a mis-configured project)

Remove the "JRE System Library"

Hit "Add Library ...", Select "JRE System Library" and add the appropriate JRE for the project (eg. 'Workspace default JRE')

Hit "Finish" in the library selection and "OK" in the project properties and then wait for the re-build of the project

Comment: I just removed the JRE system library and then added it again, still getting the same compilation error. I have no idea what is wrong lol

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I know it's late but it can help others...
Try checking if the `module-info.java` exists and if it is in the same package as your class. This will probably solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I get the soluion ,and the solution is little simple,you have to to check that your **module-info.java** should be in the same package (It should not be with any class of the package or with any folder [Screenshot of Java Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0SHh.png))

Comment: Pardon me, but your answer seems the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948896/unresolved-compilation-problem-exception-using-joptionpane/68550982#68550982). Can you explain what your answer contains that is **not** contained in the other answers?